# How can I get data from this link into a JSON?

Tags: python, asp.net, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the search results with Python from this link into a JSON file, but normal request methods seem not functioning in this case. How can extract all the results?
 url= https://apps.usp.org/app/worldwide/medQualityDatabase/reportResults.html?country=Ethiopia%2BGhana%2BKenya%2BMozambique%2BNigeria%2BCambodia%2BLao+PDR%2BPhilippines%2BThailand%2BViet+Nam%2BBolivia%2BColombia%2BEcuador%2BGuatemala%2BGuyana%2BPeru&period=2017%2B2016%2B2015%2B2014%2B2013%2B2012%2B2011%2B2010%2B2009%2B2008%2B2007%2B2006%2B2005%2B2004%2B2003&conclusion=Both&testType=Both&counterfeit=Both&recordstart=50

my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(url)
results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
```

Why am I not getting the full source code of the page?

Comment: Pls..can you be more specific ??...which language are you trying make it?...and how is your code?

Comment: just updated.sry